# Filtering ObserverableCollection to display only certain items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, icollectionview

I was following this link here: http://jacobmsaylor.com/?p=1270

but i'm having problems with it, trying to make tweaks to it

```
<ListBox Name="PageList_ListBox" MouseDoubleClick="PageList_ListBox_OnMouseDoubleClick"
                             Background="#FFC9C9C9" Margin="0,5,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding PageCollection, ElementName=This}">
```

.

```
public static ObservableCollection<MLBPage> _PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<MLBPage>();
public static ObservableCollection<MLBPage> PageCollection
        {
            get { return _PageCollection; }
        }

public ICollectionView _PageCollectionView { get; set; }

_PageCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_PageCollection);

private bool FilterLeadersList(object item)
{
  MLBPage page = item as MLBPage;
  if (page.templateName.Contains("Leaders List"))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My MLBPage object has 2 types... where the "templateName" can be either "Leaders List" or "Leader Headshots".. now when I filter the collection by adding to a button:

```
_PageCollectionView.Filter = FilterLeadersList;
```

the whole collection just filters (the _PageCollection binded to a listbox turns blank) instead of only the items that contain "Leaders List" within the name....

any help on how i can modify this to work?

Comment: to the first guy that helped me so much and deleted your answer.. repost it and i'll give you credit.  it was my fault.  your code probably worked i just messed up as i needed to compare templateType and not templateName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code into:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MLBPage> _PageCollection = new ObservableCollection<MLBPage>();            
 public ICollectionView _PageCollectionView { get; set; }
```

just do this once (eg. within ctor)

```
 //ctor
 _PageCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_PageCollection);
 _PageCollectionView.Filter = FilterLeadersList,
```

use clear, add , remove to alter your _PageCollection.

bind your listbox to your view

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding _PageCollectionView}"/>
```

use Refresh to refresh your filter

```
 _PageCollectionView.Refresh();
```

Comment: btw your original binding dont work because _PageCollection is not a public PROPERTY

Comment: blindmeis edited OP.  just didn't want to clutter it with too much so that people actually read the post =[

Comment: hm it's weird.. so i followed your instructions.. it filters literally everything (listbox is just empty).  my listbox turns up blank when i run the program.  but if i comment out "_PageCollectionView.Filter = FilterLeadersList;" the whole playlist comes up.. so i'm not sure..

Comment: i just double checked to make sure a template name in there is NOT leaders list.. sigh i just don't know why it wont work

Comment: wait think i know why... brb

Comment: it worked.. my fault.  i was using templateName instead of templateType... thank you