# Filter a listview with 2 columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, search

This is the listview in xaml

```
 <ListView x:Name="jobsListView_manageajob" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="456" Margin="21,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242" FontSize="15" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="jobsListView_manageajob_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Job #" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobNumberListView1}" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Job Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JobNameListView1}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I'm not really sure how I populate it, I'm very unfamiliar with MVVM but this is what I used

```
 private void populateJobsListView()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sCONN);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Job_Number, Name from Jobs", conn);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string jobNumber = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(0));
            string jobName = Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(1));
            jobsListView_manageajob.Items.Add(new { JobNameListView1 = jobName, JobNumberListView1 = jobNumber });
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Now I simply need to filter the listbox according to the text inside of a search box. So as I type the terms the listview element narrows down. I thought I could re-populate the listview according to the sql statement but that seemed ineffecient. I would like to do this using the textchanged property of my textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextChanged` handler can assign a delegate to `jobsListView_manageajob.Items.Filter`. That will cause the list to be filtered automatically.

Check the docs for `Filter` for more details.

Comment: How would this look in the code? I want to filter by using the text in the text box. jobsListView_manageajob.Items.Filter = delegate(); ?

Comment: That's a very general question. The docs are the best place to find out about this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/ms752348.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should read something about binding, then your task will get really easy :)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541686/filtering-observerablecollection-to-display-only-certain-items/22542377#22542377) is an answer how you can filter a collection

- populate a collection with your data from your db
- create a icollectionview for filtering
- bind your listview itemssource to your view
- refresh your view when your text has changed